# How to assign a sum of counts of IDs and join it to each IDs row in the derived table?

Tags: sql

I have trouble with the summing of counts of identities of the table.
Can you help me to create a query with using pseudo query for understanding the main algorithm of selecting and summing?

Example of my problem:
I have the Table1

```
|    ID    |  IsDidSmthBad  |   
| -------- | -------------- | 
|    132   |       1        |
|    207   |       1        |
|    314   |       1        |
|    4000  |       1        |
|    558   |       1        |
|    669   |       1        |
|    787   |       1        |
|    899   |       1        |
```

and after selecting with conditions it must be like:

```
|    ID    |  IsDidSmthBad  |   
| -------- | -------------- | 
|    132   |       8        |
|    207   |       8        |
|    314   |       8        |
|    4000  |       8        |
|    558   |       8        |
|    669   |       8        |
|    787   |       8        |
|    899   |       8        |
```

Tables are derived.
How can I make this?

P.S All data collect from normalized tables

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products. Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL 8+ or SQL Server, then you may use `COUNT()` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) OVER () AS IsDidSmthBad
FROM Table1;
```

If the above doesn't work, then try:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, t2.cnt AS IsDidSmthBad
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Table1) t2;
```